# Forwarding same port for different addresses using ssh

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

On network `A` we have hosts `192.168.0.1`, `192.168.0.2` and `192.168.0.3`. On a separate physical network `B` I want the above hosts to appear to be on the local network for a set of specific ports (same ports on all the hosts).

I have got a working SSH connection (Client on `A`, Server on `B`) and the host on `B` has `GatewayPorts=clientspecified` (and service restarted).

The host on `B` has multiple IP addresses defined that match the ones above.

The SSH connection is opened with `-R 192.168.0.1:1234:192.168.0.1:1234 -R 192.168.0.2:1234:192.168.0.2:1234 -R 192.168.0.2:1234:192.168.0.2:1234`

According to `-v` the ports are successfully bound.

Opening a connection from any host on Network `B` to any of the mentioned addresses on port `1234` always connects to the same host on network `A` - i.e. not (necessarily) the one wanted.

According to `-v` the incoming connection is on the correct IP address but it forwards to the wrong one.

Is this a bug in SSH or am I doing something wrong?

Please see the diagram here (I can't post an image apparently)
http://dev.dj-djl.com/images/port%20forwarding%20over%20ssh.png

Comment: Should this be on Server Fault?

Comment: A diagram would help

Comment: @Lawrence I've added a diagram now

Comment: Can't suggest a solution at the moment - can't think what's going on, however, a few more bits of information that may be helpful: - does it work if you use three separate ssh sessions? - what does `netstat -anp | grep :1234` on the ssh server show? - how are the machines on `192.168.1.x` routing to `192.168.0.x`?

Comment: Just an update (sorry for the delay) using separate session does work.
It's a bit of a headache to maintain but it's better than nothing